# Why data is suddendly null here?

Tags: javascript, graphql, svelte, sveltekit, urql

Why this behavior?

#### Reproduction steps:

1. Go to https://stackblitz.com/edit/sveltejs-kit-template-default-9dvq26
2. Open a new window of the same stackblitz project
3. Click on the button "Delete Team"
4. Suddendly the worst becomes reality in the other window: `data: null`!

#### GIF

[image: issDataNull2]

#### Code:

- index.svelte:

```html
<script lang="ts">
  import { gql, operationStore, query, mutation, subscription } from "@urql/svelte";

  const GamesQuery = gql`
    query games {
      games {
        id
        team {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  `;

  const PlayersQuery = gql`
    query players {
      players {
        id
        team {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  `;

  const TeamsQuery = gql`
    query teams {
      teams {
        id
        gameID
        game {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  `;

  const AddTeamToGameQuery = gql`
    mutation addTeamToGame($gameID: ID!) {
      addTeamToGame(gameID: $gameID)
    }
  `;

  const DeleteTeamFromGameQuery = gql`
    mutation deleteTeamFromGame($gameID: ID!) {
      deleteTeamFromGame(gameID: $gameID)
    }
  `;

  const AddTeamToPlayerQuery = gql`
    mutation addTeamToPlayer($playerID: ID!) {
      addTeamToPlayer(playerID: $playerID)
    }
  `;

  const DeleteTeamFromPlayerQuery = gql`
    mutation deleteTeamFromPlayer($playerID: ID!) {
      deleteTeamFromPlayer(playerID: $playerID)
    }
  `;

    const addTeamToGame = mutation({query: AddTeamToGameQuery});
    const deleteTeamFromGame = mutation({query: DeleteTeamFromGameQuery});
    const addTeamToPlayer = mutation({query: AddTeamToPlayerQuery});
    const deleteTeamFromPlayer = mutation({query: DeleteTeamFromPlayerQuery});

  const gamesStore = operationStore(GamesQuery, {}, { requestPolicy: "cache-and-network" });
  query(gamesStore);

  const playersStore = operationStore(PlayersQuery, {}, { requestPolicy: "cache-and-network" });
  query(playersStore);

  const teamsStore = operationStore(TeamsQuery, {}, { requestPolicy: "cache-and-network" });
  query(teamsStore);

  const ActQuery = gql`
  subscription act {
    act {
      action
      resourceType
      resourceID
    }
  }`

  const actsStore = operationStore(ActQuery);

    subscription(actsStore);

  $: games = $gamesStore.data?.games;
  $: players = $playersStore.data?.players;
  $: teams = $teamsStore.data?.teams;

  async function onAddTeamToGame(id) {
    const result = await addTeamToGame({gameID: id});
    if (result.error) console.error(result.error)
  }

  async function onDeleteTeamFromGame(id) {
    const result = await deleteTeamFromGame({gameID: id});
    if (result.error) console.error(result.error)
  }

  async function onAddTeamToPlayer(id) {
    const result = await addTeamToPlayer({playerID: id});
    if (result.error) console.error(result.error)
  }

  async function onDeleteTeamFromPlayer(id) {
    const result = await deleteTeamFromPlayer({playerID: id});
    if (result.error) console.error(result.error)
  }
</script>

<h1>Games</h1>
<ul>
{#each games || [] as game}
  <li>ID: {game.id} - Team: {JSON.stringify(game.team)} - 
  {#if game.team}
    <button type="button" on:click={() => onDeleteTeamFromGame(game.id)}>
    Delete team
    </button>
  {:else}
    <button type="button" on:click={() => onAddTeamToGame(game.id)}>
    Add new team
    </button>
  {/if}
  </li>
{/each}
</ul>

<br>

<h1>Players</h1>
<ul>
{#each players || [] as player}
  <li>ID: {player.id} - Team: {JSON.stringify(player.team)} - 
  {#if player.team}
    <button type="button" on:click={() => onDeleteTeamFromPlayer(player.id)}>
    Delete team
    </button>
  {:else}
    <button type="button" on:click={() => onAddTeamToPlayer(player.id)}>
    Add new team
    </button>
  {/if}
  </li>
{/each}
</ul>

<br>

<h1>Teams</h1>
<ul>
{#each teams || [] as team}
  <li>ID: {team.id} - Game: {JSON.stringify(team.game)} - Player: {JSON.stringify(team.player)}</li>
{/each}
</ul>
```

Comment: step 6. post the code you have issue with in stackoverflow - not a link and a gif

Comment: I cannot post the code, because I don't know what is the part of the codebase I have problem with.

Comment: so, you don't even know what code is run when you click on a button? Ask the person who wrote the code, they'll tell you

Comment: @FredHors You should create a minimal reproducible example that can be turned into a self-contained question. Questions should not require people to run and debug live code off-site.

Comment: That is a minimal reproducible example already. Really.

Comment: @FredHors: Hardly. There are four different operations, even though the problem is in just one of them.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is the intended behavior; It's deleting the team, therefore setting its data to null.

If you mean "Why are the teams disappearing from the Games section?", then that's *most likely* an error in the Svelte code or a badly formatted graphql call.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I invalidate the team it works. After that I invalidate the Game and data becomes null. This is the strange behavior. Urql co-author answered me here: https://github.com/FormidableLabs/urql/discussions/2417#discussioncomment-2621202 but i still cannot understand how to fix: can you help me?

Comment: Looks like some kind of code contradiction:  A non-nullable entity, as the name suggests, can't be null, but deleting a team looks like it nulls it out. Hence the "[...] as we see a null in your array which is not allowed." part of the comment you linked.

Comment: I really do not understand. I'm lost.

Comment: Let me explain from the beginning. It looks like your code is declaring a non-nullable entity/variable, which, as the name implies, cannot be set to a value of null. The code also seems to try setting the entity/variable to null, which is impossible, throwing an error. This is most likely (I don't know much about gql so don't quote me on this) a bad graphql call or variable mismatch.